# Android: How do I always start the app from a particular activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, widget

I have an activity `Alert`, which is defined in the manifest like so :

```
        <activity android:name="Alert"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
              android:launchMode="singleInstance"
              android:noHistory="true">
    </activity>
```

I also have another activity `Config` which is a setting page for a homescreen widget and is defined as

```
        <activity android:name=".Config"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

The `Alert` activity is shown when the user clicks on the widget. Now my problem is that, after running the application and returning to Home screen, when I long press the home-key and select the app, the `Alert` activity is shown. Is there a way to prevent this from happening and always start from the `Config` activity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To illustrate this problem, you should understand the way Android handles activities. When you press 'home' button, your `Alert` is considered to be still *alive*, but it is in a `pause` mode. So, when you long press, it is switched back and just `resume` your previous top-of-the-pile activity, which is the `Alert` in this case.

So, you may consider to, in your `onPause` event of Alert, to tell Android to end the Activity instead of putting it to pause.

Comment: Thanks. What should I call to end it? `finish()` does not work.

Comment: Ok maybe finish() is not working because I am using it for my other activity also. Could it be the reason? If so, in that case, how can I get it to work?